# Currency manager with wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

friends;
i'm working with wpf and previous working with windows forms
the currency manger work with me without any problem in windows form
but not work with me in wpf 
how can i use currency manger with wpf

The type or namespace name `CurrencyManager' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

```
class dealWithCurrancyManager
{

    #region Variable Declartion
    OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Properties.Settings.Default.dPath + ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=azouz(2016)");
    OleDbDataAdapter da;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
///// this line here display error
    public CurrencyManager cur;

    #endregion;
```

Comment: That class is a part of the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly and should not be used in a WPF application.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
  private void btnNext_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
   System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager bc;

   bc = (CurrencyManager) this.BindingContext[this.dsEmployeeList1, "Employees"];
   bc.Position += 1;
   UpdateDisplay();
  }
```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8b597c2c-5b11-4588-9727-f53f0b9623e4/navigating-to-the-next-row-in-a-dataset-using-wpf?forum=wpf